# How to handle a case when top() is called on an empty stack

Tags: c++, stack, destructor, assert

I have implemented a stack class. I have the regular top and pop functions. As pop is a void function it is easier to detect if the stack is empty and just print a message if it is. But the top returns a constant reference of what is stored on the top. How to handle a situation where the stack is empty and top is called on the stack? I tried to use the assert statement. A related question is that whether the destructor gets called if the assertion fails?

Comment: Typically you would [throw an exception](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Exception_Handling) when a member function is called for an invalid state.

Comment: Destructors are unlikely to be called when assertion fails. They are not even guaranteed to be called when there is an uncaught exception.